# Get values of multiple inputs, then output each into different elements

Tags: jquery, each

I have a list of twenty checkboxes that allow a user (of the Wordpress Dashboard) to select colors that are used elsewhere in the site. I want a little preview before each checkbox that shows the color visually. HTML wise this is what it looks like. This is generated in the Wordpress Dashboard so I've got little control over it, although I can change things around with jQuery.

```
<div id="acf-highcharts_kleuren_multiple" class="field">
  <ul class="checkbox_list checkbox">
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="'#FEB601'" name="fields[field_51826b4cf2fa2][]" class="checkbox" id="acf-field-highcharts_kleuren_multiple">Yellow</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="'#FF9326'" name="fields[field_51826b4cf2fa2][]" class="checkbox" id="acf-field-highcharts_kleuren_multiple">Orange</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="'#EA312C'" name="fields[field_51826b4cf2fa2][]" class="checkbox" id="acf-field-highcharts_kleuren_multiple">Red</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="'#A21A55'" name="fields[field_51826b4cf2fa2][]" class="checkbox" id="acf-field-highcharts_kleuren_multiple">Purple</label><li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'm trying to change the color of a div element via jQuery. I want to get the color value from an input field and then output that value as the background-color of that div. I'm able to get all values via the alert. And the code below changes the color of the first div to the value of the first input. What do I need to do to change all divs to a different color corresponding to the correct input field?

**Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LKhS5/**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){


    $(function() {

        $("#acf-highcharts_kleuren_multiple.field ul.checkbox_list li label input").each(function() {

            alert($(this).val());

            $("#acf-highcharts_kleuren_multiple.field ul.checkbox_list li label div").each(function() {

                $(this).css("background-color", $("#acf-highcharts_kleuren_multiple.field ul.checkbox_list li label input").val() );

            });
        });

    });


    $("#acf-highcharts_kleuren_multiple.field ul.checkbox_list li label").prepend("<div>&nbsp;</div>");


});
```

Comment: It seems pointless to put your code inside of a closure, inside of an anonymous function. Maybe that's just me, but I don't see the point. The anonymous function that you are passing to `$.ready()` is already a closure.

Comment: Also, you've assigned multiple elements the same ID. This is invalid. ID must be unique per element per document.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean with the 'same ID'?

Comment: @BartDeVuyst All your inputs have id "acf-field-highcharts_kleuren_multiple". This is invalid.

Comment: Thanks. Soo obvious that I didn't see it. :-)

I changed the Fiddle but I get the first color. I'd like to have each inputs' color applied to the **<div>**.

http://jsfiddle.net/LKhS5/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - your values: you have single quotation marks inside double quotation marks `"'#FEB601'"`. Remove single quotation marks to get `"#FEB601"`.

Now this code works: (http://jsfiddle.net/GXuU5/1/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // first I create divs

    $("#acf-highcharts_kleuren_multiple.field ul.checkbox_list li label").prepend("<div>&nbsp;</div>");

    // now I can change colors of created divs

    $(function() {

        $("#acf-highcharts_kleuren_multiple.field ul.checkbox_list li label input").each(function() {
            color = $(this).val();

            $(this).prev().css("background-color", color );
        });

    });


});
```

Comment: Thanks Furas, I found out about the nested quotes too. Thanks for the helping me out!

Comment: It even works without removing the single quotes when I try it out in Wordpress!

Comment: For me in jQuery single quotes inside doubel qoutes doesn't work `.css("background-color", "'#aaaaaa'" );` but this works `.css("background-color", "#aaaaaa" );` Wordpress is not jQuery so it can remove some quotes.